# How to remove whitespace from specifc line?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Say I have a file structured so:

> X sequence 1 is this
>
> ABCDE FGH HIJ
>
> X sequence 2 is this
>
> ABCDE FGH HIJ

How would I conditionally remove whitespace? I know the snippet below will remove all whitespace. How would I be able to remove whitespace only on the lines beginning with X?

```
sed 's/ //g'
```

I also had seen

```
 '/^startswith
```

been used, but can't seem to tie them together to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **awk,** the general syntax is address followed by a code block, where "address" is either a line number or a `/regex/` or a comma-separated `from,to` range.

So if you want to match lines starting with X and apply a substitution to them:

```
/^X/ { gsub(/ /, ""); } { print; }
```

(The 2nd block is addressless, so it prints all lines.)

**sed's** syntax is similar, except the commands are shorter (`s/…/…/` for substitution) and single-command blocks don't need the braces. So the same task can be performed in sed using:

```
/^X/ { s/ //g; }
```

or the shorter

```
/^X/ s/ //g
```

(Sed also doesn't need an explicit "print" block since printing is already the default there, unless -n is given. But it *does* have a print command `p`.)

Comment: Excellent. I was doing similar, but over-complicating it and adding junk later one. Thank you for your help.